# Blue Dragon Coldfusion server cache issue

Tags: caching, coldfusion, bluedragon, mach-ii

I have an application build in ColdFusion MVC framework "Mach-II" and hosted on blue dragon ColdFusion server.

It causes caching issue. When i added a new page with some contents and load the page than it's working fine. But when i made some changes in the same file and hit it again its not update my changes. Its always showing me the content that i have made in the very first time. Its seems like that the server is caching my page and did not consider further changes. I have tried many solutions but failed to solve the problem.

Please let me know if you have any solution for that.

Comment: If you intentionally introduce a syntax error, what happens?

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit too long for a comment - but it's not much of an answer.

First off, your question is quite broad for StackOverflow. If you aren't looking at the code yourself, and have nothing to show us, there is no guarantee we can help you at all.

It sounds like maybe this service is using query caching - which looks something like this.

```
<cfquery datasource="CRM" name="testQuery" cachedwithin="#CreateTimeSpan(0,0,30,0)#">
-SQL logic-
</cfquery>
```

Basically it stores a query's result in memory on the server. It can really help reduce strain on the database. It's possible that they've set a time limit on this caching feature that's longer than you'd like.

If you don't have access to the code, THIS is the issue you want to ask about first.

Edit: It may be entirely different.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13176_01/bluedragon/621/BlueDragon_621_WL_User_Guide.html#_Toc121303111

From source:

> Where ColdFusion (5 and MX) defines a ‘template cache” as a place to
>   holds templates in memory once rendered from source code, BlueDragon
>   has the same notion but refers to this as the “file cache”. In both
>   engines, a template once rendered from source will remain in the cache
>   until the server (or J2EE or .NET web app) is restarted.
>
> The cache size, specified in the Admin Console, indicates how many of
>   these cached templates to keep. It defaults to 60 but that number may
>   need to change for your application, depending on how many CFML
>   templates your application uses. One entry is used for each template
>   (CFM or CFC file) requested.
>
> It’s very important to understand that this is not caching the OUTPUT
>   of the page but rather the rendering of the template from source into
>   its internal objects. One cached instance of the template is shared
>   among all users in the application.
>
> As in ColdFusion, once the file cache is full (for instance, you set
>   it to 60 and 60 templates have been requested), then the next request
>   for a template not yet cached will force the engine to flush the
>   oldest (least recently used) entry in the cache to make room.
>   Naturally, if you set this file cache size too low, thrashing in the
>   cache could occur as room is made for files only to soon have the
>   flushed file requested again.

It sounds like you might have to either restart the ColdFusion application or clear the Template Cache in the CFAdmin.

Comment: its not a code issue. its even did not show any changes in Application.cfc file.

Comment: So thats the reason why i did not show any piece of code

Comment: I think its an server cache issue

Comment: @UsmanAsghar You may be right. I found some documentation from BlueDragon and put it in my answer.