# Facing cache issue on viviotech server and flush cache through code - coldfusion

Tags: .htaccess, caching, coldfusion, bluedragon

On viviotech server - i am facing issue of cache the document. When i am adding new page like if i add page and dump test in it.

```
<cfdump var="test">
```

Then again changing the content of page. It is not showing updates to me. I have tried every option which i found to flush the cache or disable the cache. But nothing is helpful. I have also added headers and htaccess file with no cache code but that is also not helpful.

Cache can be turn off through blue dragon administrator link but that is also not working due to unknown reason and got no help from the support of vivio tech.

Can any one help me how i can flush the cache through code. I have bluedragon administrator code on server.

Comment: Voting to close as it's a hosting question, not a programming question. Raise a ticket with Viviotech (who are just a shared hosting provider)

Comment: Hi #Adam, yes, it is hosting question. But there is no information to disable trusted cache. Also cache is only for cfm and cfc files. It seems that, i have to do some thing through coldfusion. Can you please help me, if you have any thing for me to try through coldfusion. Also blue dragon is installed on the server.

Comment: `<cfdump var="#test#">` would probably be more interesting

Comment: Like I said "Raise a ticket with Viviotech".

Comment: Hi @AbdulRauf - I hope you'll forgive Adam Cameron. He's our local prickly pear. Regarding your issue - there was another recent question pertaining to Blue Dragon and caching, specifically. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35222773/blue-dragon-coldfusion-server-cache-issue/35223497#35223497 --- If you have access to CFadmin, you may be able to clear the template cache and resolve your issue, or at least reduce its impact on you. Hope this helps.

Comment: #James. if i tried this. it would not cache until the error resolved of undefined variable. :)

Comment: #TRose. Yes, right. I already find this. But cfadmin is not working on my site and i also lost the links. I am finding a way to flush or turn it off through some code. I have found something which could be helpful to flush or turn it off through code.